# Bernoulli Differential Equation of Second Order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How one can solve a Bernoulli differential equation of second order?
i.e., solve the DE
\begin{align}
\frac{{d^2 y}}{{dx^2 }} + p\left( x \right)\frac{{dy}}{{dx}} 
+ q \left( x \right)y = g\left( x \right)y^n 
\end{align}
where $p$, $q$ and $g$ are continuous functions in an interval $(a,b)$ and $n$ is a real number.

Comment: What have you tried?  The first order method is:  Note $y=0$ is a solution and then divide the equation by $y^n$, eliminating $y$ from the RHS.  Then set $z = y^{1-n}$ and change to an equation in $z$.  This change of variable renders the problem simple enough to do.  If this doesn't work, what else have you tried?

Comment: I tried that. I don't think it is simple enough; because if we let $z=y^{1-n}$, this change of variable yields that \begin{align} \frac{1}{{1 - n}}z'' + \frac{n}{{\left( {1 - n} \right)^2 }} \cdot 
z^{ - {\textstyle{1 \over {1 - n}}}} 
\cdot z'^2 + \frac{1}{{1 - n}}p\left( x \right)z' + q\left( x \right)z = g\left( x \right) \end{align} so how come? let us try simple example. Solve $ y'' - xy' + 2y = xy^3 $ ?

Comment: Do you have a reference to a source that calls these "Bernoulli differential equations of second order"?

Comment: Indeed no, i don't have a source; its mine. At all not important to me to know a source for this type of D.E. but to solve it. Let us think about more simple case when $p(x)=a$,$q(x)=b$,$g(x)=c$, i.e., \begin{align} y'' + ay' + by = cy^n . \end{align} As example solve $y'' -2 y' + y = y^3$. Thank you for your concern

Comment: ah, i got the solution for the last D.E. \begin{align}
y'' + ay' + by = cy^n 
\end{align} where $a,b$ and $c$ are constant. This nonlinear DE with missing $x$, so make the substitution $\nu = y'$ and $y''=\nu \frac{{d\nu }}{{dy}}$ so that the D.E becomes \begin{equation} 
\nu \frac{{d\nu }}{{dy}} + a\nu  + by = cy^n 
   \end{equation} or \begin{equation} 
\nu d\nu  + \left( {a\nu  + by - cy^n } \right)dy = 0,
\end{equation} which is not an exact equation, so that by choosing an a propirate integrating factor we get a solution.  Tell me if I am wrong. It remains the original case (with $x$).

Comment: ..... so that by choosing an "appropriate"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose that  someone could answer to your question, i.e. give an analytic formula for $y(x)$ as general solution of :
\begin{align}
\frac{{d^2 y}}{{dx^2 }} + p\left( x \right)\frac{{dy}}{{dx}} 
+ q \left( x \right)y = g\left( x \right)y^n 
\end{align}
Then, this result would apply in case of $g(x)=0$ :
\begin{align}
\frac{{d^2 y}}{{dx^2 }} + p\left( x \right)\frac{{dy}}{{dx}} 
+ q \left( x \right)y = 0 
\end{align}

So, the general solution of the homogeneous second order ODE would be discovered. This would be a great discovery !.

As a consequence, you will have to wait probably un long time until a genious gives the general solution of your problem.

Comment: This is more or less what I said in my (now deleted) answer to this question. The OP apparently prefers to wait.